# Form Validation Error when a required field is remained blank in django

Tags: django, forms, validation, view

I want to have errors as a label above a field if it is not filled.
This is my views.py:

```
 @login_required(login_url='user_profile:login')
    def NewWriting(request):
        if request.method=="POST":
            form=WritingForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                post=form.save(commit=False)
                post.author=request.user
                post.save()
                return redirect('user_profile:index')

        else:
            form = WritingForm()
            subject = Subject.objects.all()
            return render(request,'user_profile/writing_form.html', {'form':form , 'subject':subject})
```

what should I add to my code?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your form class ...

Option 1:

- If you really want the user to be able to submit the form with empty data and then specifically show them that error using the form, set the `required=False` kwarg for the specific field in your `WritingForm` class. Then override the `clean_<fieldname>` ([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/)) method and then you could do:

  ```
  def clean_<fieldname>:
      if self.cleaned_data['<fieldname>'].strip() == '':
          raise ValidationError('This field cannot be blank!')
      return self.cleaned_data['<fieldname>']
  ```

Replacing `<fieldname>` with whatever that fieldname is.

Option 2:

- The [default for any form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#required) is to make all fields required (IE: `required=True` kwarg on the field). So in general, if the field is required most browsers will at least move the cursor to the empty field and won't allow the form to be submitted while there is no data in the field.

You also need to return a bound form in the case where `form.is_valid()` returns False or you won't ever see the errors (right now you don't return anything if the form is invalid). Please see the django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#the-view) for a common functional view pattern using forms.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another all to render if the form is not valid, and in your template, you need to make use of `form.errors`.  Something like  this should work so that form validation errors are then passed back to the UI/template for display to the user:

```
@login_required(login_url='user_profile:login')
def NewWriting(request):
    form = None
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=WritingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post=form.save(commit=False)
            post.author=request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('user_profile:index')

    if form is None:
        form = WritingForm()
    subject = Subject.objects.all()
    return render(request,'user_profile/writing_form.html', {'form':form , 'subject':subject})
```